# Ionic build: difference between --prod and --release flags?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build, ionic3

When running an `ionic build` I'm curious as to the difference between the `--prod` and `--release` flags?

The [Ionic build docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/) state:

> **--prod**    Build the application for production
>   **--release** Create a Cordova release build

and while the [Cordova CLI ref](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-prepare-command) doesn't mention a `--prod` flag, it states the following for `--release`:

> Perform a release build. This typically translates to release mode for
>   the underlying platform being built.

Looking at the difference in the build output, building with `--prod` seems to run an **Ionic** 'production' build, in that it also runs the `ngc` and `uglify` (which itself runs `cleancss`) tasks.

And when I run a build with `--release`, I seem to get a **Cordova** release build, which (per the docs) attempts to run a release build on whatever platform you're targeting.

Are those the only differences, or am I over-simplifying?

For reference, note the following output APK filesizes:

- Prod flag: 9.8 MB
- Release flag: 11.7 MB
- Prod + Release flags: 8.9 MB

I'm using the latest (ATTOW) version of the Ionic Framework (3.9.2) and CLI (3.20.0).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Prod optimizes the code, Release makes it build in a different way so
>   the app can be released to the stores. You have to use both for a fast
>   version that can be released.

As Sujan12 says on [this link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/release-build-much-slower-than-prod/103954).

Comment: The current documentation for publishing to the app store only uses the --prod flag. Is --release no longer used? https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/app-store

Answer (score 0):

This solution may sound stupid but you need to delete/uninstall the old .apk from your android phone, and then try installing new.

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

worked for me!