# ionic cordova build android difference between

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Please Explain me difference between:

1. ionic cordova build android -> .apk Slowin loading
2. ionic cordova build android --prod -> .apk Fast in loading
3. ionic cordova build android --prod --release -> .apk Slow in loading

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic build: difference between --prod and --release flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581363/ionic-build-difference-between-prod-and-release-flags)

Answer (score 1):

Without flags it generates the apk debug version. And with release it generates the apk ready for the store but unsigned when you sign it you can upload it.

The --prod flag:

> This will minify your app’s code as Ionic’s source and also remove any debugging capabilities from the APK.

Comment: are you taking about --prod flag ?

Comment: Does release have any effect on code optimization. I do not want to release it on app store just want to test my code in my mobile. So  will  release will effect anything in code optimization ?

Comment: If you want to test it on mobile but not uploading to the store you should use ionic cordova build android --prod . Not --release. The release flag does not have any optimization for that are the --prod flag or also you can use the the zipalign tool, you should see this link:  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html