# ionic 4 build --prod production behave different with non-production

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

Any of you build the app with

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod

ionic cordova build ios
```

When use the real device to test, it will behave different. Some working on build without --prod, some working on --prod.

So what should I do to make it the same? but also need Angular performance.

Comment: _"When use the real device to test, it will behave different. Some working on build without --prod, some working on --prod."_. How is it behaving differently? There's nothing to go on here.

Comment: Prod optimizes the code.For more info check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581363/ionic-build-difference-between-prod-and-release-flags